# Search filter with normal TextView file

Tags: android, filter

This is my code. I want to add filter so that when i search with "Teacher" then result show Teacher from below TextView only. its without any listview arraylist. how it is possible ???.

```
        <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
        android:orientation="Vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" > 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent" 
    android:capitalize="characters" 
    android:text="University" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text2" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent" 
    android:capitalize="characters" 
    android:text="School" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text3" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent" 
    android:capitalize="characters" 
    android:text="Madam" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text4" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_parent" 
android:capitalize="characters" 
android:text="Teacher" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text5"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_parent" 
android:capitalize="characters" 
android:text="Master" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can try using autocomplete textview

Answer (score 0):

There is lack of information in your question. It is suggested, post your question with as much as description you could provide. Any ways, let's start. If you're wondering about searching and filter, first there are couple of questions could raise over here.
-> What type of *app* or simple program is this?
-> You're *searching*  some data but from where?
-> What type of teacher information you wanna search? *name* , *id*, pay or something?
You have to make your mind like: *Hey! i am searching about teacher but what? name or his/her pay or what? and from where? convert this logic into code* 
You can achieve searching with these ways
-> Add search in toolbar 
-> Use custom `Edit text` to make it act as `seachView`
-> Last but not least, You could use `recyclerView` `filter` to filter the items or you could use `room persistence` query to search items. Luckily i was facing same problem couple or days back. Now i am going to provide you link how i achieved searchView with toolbar or without toolbar and what was best for me to make it work, what was better decision for me, by the way i preferred to use custom `edittext`. Anyways, here it is: 
[MVVM Recyclerview Livedata Room SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58973793/12397978) 
Kindly read each and everything in this link from question to comments to answers, i am assuming you have basic knowledge about `MVVM` `Room persistence` `RecyclerView`. 
And This one is just recyclerView and filter
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/
I Hope this helps, Thankyou().

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should practice some best practices to do this stuff but I am giving solution as per your requirements. see the code bellow

XML:

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_search"
        android:hint="Search Here"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUniversity"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="University" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSchool"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="School" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMadam"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Madam" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTeacher"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Teacher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMaster"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Master" />

</LinearLayout>`
```

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView _teacher,_university,_school,_master,_madam;
    EditText search;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        search = findViewById(R.id.edittext_search);
        _teacher = findViewById(R.id.tvTeacher);
        _university = findViewById(R.id.tvUniversity);
        _school = findViewById(R.id.tvSchool);
        _master = findViewById(R.id.tvMaster);
        _madam = findViewById(R.id.tvMadam);

        search();
    }

    private void search() {
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            //Hide all view first
            _teacher.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _university.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _school.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _madam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _master.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().equals("teacher")){
                _teacher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else if(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().equals("university")){
                _university.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else if(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().equals("school")){
                _school.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to show result As Value..Teacher ..but it was a  just  example... .. item ... As like teacher other value filter

Comment: I have updated my answer. is it ok ? if so accept my answer otherwise ask me again i will answer again